# Не удаётся вставить запись в базу данных

Tags: php, sql, запрос

Друзья, возник следующие вопрос. В php-коде я делаю так, чтобы запись вставлялась в базу данных, но результат не оправдывает своих ожиданий. В phpAdmin всё работает хорошо. Вот вам ссылка на тот самый ресурс https://testsiteforme.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/themes/generalthemeforwebhost/make_order.html. !!ВНИМАНИЕ!! пока только реализовал ввод имени и имени любимого человека(заполнение только первых и вторых строк формы). Как можно решить данную проблему? Буду очень признателен за помощь.
if(isset($_REQUEST['to_make_order']))
 {

```
    if($_REQUEST['info_answer_name']!=null && $_REQUEST['info_answer_lover']!=null) {
        $host = "---";
        $login = "---";
        $password = "---";
        $db_name = "---";
        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $login, $password, $db_name);

        if($link) {
            echo 'Соединение установлено.'; //+
        } else {
            echo 'ошибка к подключению к базе данных 1' . mysqli_error($link);
            exit;
        }

        $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `clients` (`first_name`, `lover_name`) 
                    VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['info_answer_name']."','".$_REQUEST['info_answer_lover']."');");

        if ($query) {
           echo "Удачный запрос";
        } else {
            echo "Неудачный запрос";
            die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    } else {
        echo 'регистрация не прошла успешно';
    }

    mysqli_close();
}
```

Comment: Ошибки, проблемы? Экстрасенсы в отпуске. И ещё вам стоит почитать про подготовленные запросы и SQL-инъекции

Comment: дело в том, что я тебе не могу сказать про них, так как он мне не выдаёт их

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перезаписать ваш запрос в стиле

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO client (first_name, lover_name) VALUES(?, ?)";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    //'ss' это параметры, которые вы передаете s - string, i - integer, d - double
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $info_answer_name, $info_lover_name);
if($statement->execute()){
    print 'Correct ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />';
    }else{
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $statement->close();
```

Если не прокнет - напишите какую ошибку он вам выдает

Comment: Привет, Foxey. Спасибо за твой вариант решения. Одну ошибку я в своём запросе нашёл, исправил, но в итоге он не хочет даже выводить ошибку, делаю точно также как ты мне написал. Не знаю в чём дело. В принципе я готов тебе сказать тебе все учётные данные от хостинга, чтобы ты мне помог, может я по глупости своей не вижу её.

Comment: @egorkorottsev, теперь он выдает только то, что соединение установлено. С помощью чего ты собираешь проект? При выведении ошибки в консоли должны вылетать сообщения. Лично юзаю eclipse

Comment: не собираю я никак проект, я использую только встроенную IDE на сайте хостинга.